# Page Padding not working

Tags: pagination

I've added the page padding parameter to my pagination tags but it's still rendering only 5 pages.

There are hundreds of pages so I know that it's not an issue with the amount of content.

Any thoughts?

```
{paginate}
{if {total_pages} > 1}
<nav class="centered" role="toolbar">
<ul class="pagination">
{pagination_links page_padding="10"}
{previous_page}<li><a href="{pagination_url}">&laquo;</a></li>{/previous_page}

{page}<li {if current_page}class="active"{/if}><a href="{pagination_url}">{pagination_page_number}</a></li>{/page}

{next_page}<li><a href="{pagination_url}">&raquo;</a></li>{/next_page}
{/pagination_links}
</ul>
</nav>
{/if}
{/paginate}
```

Comment: What version of EE are you running? This was added in 2.8.

Comment: Ah. I'm running 2.7.3. Is there a way I can replicate the effect without upgrading?

Comment: You could try some of the [third party pagination add-ons](http://devot-ee.com/search/results?keywords=pagination&addon_version_support=ee2), but I'm not sure if any provide this specific functionality.